# Always show taskbar in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

If I maximize the web browser or other applications, it covers the taskbar as in the first screenshot:

[image: Taskbar covered by webbrowser]

In the settings, I un-checked `Automatically hide the taskbar` as in the second screenshot:

[image: windows 11 setting about taskbar]

I think there is an option like 'Fix the taskbar' but I cannot find it.

How can I make Windows 11 always display the taskbar?

**Edit**

It is a Samsung Galaxy laptop, and I missed something in the original question. It does not always happen.

When I connect this laptop to external monitors, the taskbar is shows which is normal.
But I disconnect it and use the laptop alone, then it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are seeing in the first screen shot.

This is not happening here: 2 Production Windows 11 Pro, 1 Insider Windows 11 Pro. Edge or Chrome.

**1. Try running DISM / SFC**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**2. If that does not work:**

**(a) Try a Windows 11 Repair Install:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Start with that.

**(b) Did you upgrade from Windows 10?**  That does not always work, and it may be necessary to reinstall Windows.

**(c) Did you install 3rd party Start Button software or Explorer Patching software.** These do not always work and you may need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But the first one did not work for me, maybe because I did not say one important thing. I edited my question. Could you please see the edited part?

Comment: I looked at your post again. You should try the Repair Install (second suggestion)

Comment: It is now working in the most recent version of Windows 11! Thank you for letting me know this.